# How to remove background HDR of rendered image using compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How to remove background HDR of rendered image using compositing? I tried the below, and it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way does **not use compositing**, but avoiding having a background image in the first place.

You would just go to *Properties panel > Render tab > Film*  and check *Transparent*.

[image]

By doing that your background will not be part of the render image and will be transparent through an **Alpha channel**:

[image]
*Transparent enabled on the right*

---

That being said, there is a way to do it using the following *Compositing Nodes* setup.

[image]

The *Color Key* takes out the black from the *Environment* pass. The *Invert* changes the matte map to preferable colors. The *Alpha Over* node actually adds the transparency.

The following .blend file is the one shown in the above *Compositing Nodes* screenshot.

[image]